# MD5 uuid collision?

Tags: file-upload, file, md5, collision-detection, uuid

I'm dealing with image uploads and I'd like some suggestions on naming files and folders. Currently, I'm generating a file name using the following:

```
md5( microtime() ) . $this->user_id
```

That outputs something like:

*e89ae1857038d0e5d0f8092e6c5390b91*

I then take the first 3 characters of that file name to generate the folders.
Which will be something like:

*/e/8/9*

So it ends up being:

*/e/8/9/e89ae1857038d0e5d0f8092e6c5390b91*

I'm using the md5 so that it somewhat evenly distributes the files across the folders. Is that a good uuid? Is there a chance for collision?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any hash, there is a chance for collision.  If you think about it, a hash takes an infinite number of inputs and turns it into a finite number of outputs.

But, for all practical (non-academic) implications, there is no such thing as a collision. 2^128 is such a huge number it will never happen before even the heat death of the universe.

Comment: Even though I'm appending an incrementing user id at the end?

Comment: If your user IDs are unique, there won't be a collision that way.

Comment: Ah.  I thought your user id was *inside* the parentheses.  No, you shouldn't ever have a collision, then, by definition.

Comment: (Just to be clear, even if you were using the worst hash algorithm in the world, you still wouldn't get collisions.  For example, what if your MD5 always returned a string that contained 32 zeroes?  Your unique user id would still completely eliminate duplicates.)